# Is there a way to find the position of text in an open tab in a website in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I need a way to find the position of text in a window of a browser like chrome or firefox. Is there any way of doing this except taking screenshots of the text I want to find and then using pyautogui.locateonscreen()? I want to automate a website and the html continually changes.

Comment: You need to find the text's actual location on the screen, and not just the logical "location" within the document structure?  (i.e. it's in the second paragraph, in the third div, under the h2 heading)

Comment: the coordinates, so i can click on it

Comment: The question remains. Why not use the xpath in something like selenium and just `object.click()`?